# How to change extension of files generated by Jekyll?

Tags: ruby, jekyll

How to generate not **.html* files with Jekyll but files with another extension? I would like to patch it with *rb* plugin. Is it possible?

I tried this (googled this), but it doesn't work:

```
module Jekyll

  # Extensions to the Jekyll Page class.

  class Page

    def output_ext(ext)
      ".myext"
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: What kind of files? For example for a file sitemap.xml I get a file _site/sitemap.xml. Due to the .xml extension it is not processed by Markdown, but still interpreted by Liquid. Or do you need Markdown processing too?

Comment: Its always possible. What have you tried?

Comment: @theTinMan, I tried to rewrite output_ext in plugin. Added code example in the question.

Comment: @manatwork  I need the result of Luquid templates to be saved into _site/page.my-ext

Answer (score 1):

If you want an output to `_sites/` with your extension “from the box”, you can use only `pages` files — they're not using the `permalink` from the config, so those files would have the same extension you gave to them.

So, the smallest set is a file `page.my-ext` at the root of your project, having a YAML front matter (could be empty) like this:

```
---
---

Foo
```

Such file would be visible to the Jekyll, you could use any liquid markup inside, or use any layout for it, and then this file would be saved to the `_sites/` with the same name it was before.

You can't use such file in `/_posts/`, 'cause when there is a `permalink` set, Jekyll saves files only as `.html`.

Custom plugin with converter works for me, but also only for simple pages — posts from `/_posts/` are still getting `.html`, so it seems that it's hardcoded there.

So, the only way right now is to use simple pages instead of posts. And if you'd like to iterate through all such pages as you can do with posts, you should read on how the [pages_list module](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/api/bootstrap-api.html#jbpages_list) from Jekyll Bootstrap is made — I think it's something like that.

Comment: Pity, I need posts not pages ;-(

Comment: Well, then the only easy solution I see is to add an external script/watcher that would rewrite the extensions in the `_sites` directory as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED:

Sollution found here:
http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/

You can specify the permalinks in the markup post. It will unfortunately not work if specified in _config.yml

According to my tests, if you enter:
    permalink: /whatever/filename/with/arbitrary.xtension 

in the markup post, your index file will be named "arbitrary.xtension" and placed in the folder:
/whatever/filename/with/

For other applications where the content of the file needs to be consistent to the extension, this plugin might perhaps help you:
https://github.com/fauno/jekyll-pandoc-multiple-formats